# Ordering items that contain double quotes

Tags: c#, sorting

How would I order a list of items where some of the items contain double quotes?

- Advance
- Access
- “Chain free” deal
- Binding
- Broker

Doing this `FaqData = repo.FaqData.OrderBy(q => q.Description)` results in the following

- “Chain free” deal
- Advance
- Access
- Binding
- Broker

Tried this as well

```
 FaqData = repo.FaqData.OrderBy(q => q.QuestionDescription.Replace("”", ""))
```

Comment: You can define your own comparer by implementing the IComparer interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FaqData = repo.FaqData.OrderBy(q => q.Description.Replace(@"""",""))

OrderBy calls the delegate once per item contained in the list being sorted. The delegate should return a value which, when compared to values obtained in the same way for other items in the list, will provide a value that can be sorted.

Typically the value returned in the delegate is a property of the listed item - but because its code, it could return anything you like, including values that arn't anything to do with the items in the list.

In this example instead of returning the list property ".Description" the code is returning a new string value derived from the ".Description" property. The derivation is simply to use the .net String.Replace to replace all double-quote values with an empty string.

This means the sorting algorithm sorts on the ".Description" with double-quotes removed.

This is not very efficient if you call this sorting code many times, and could easily be done differently; either by adding a new property to the class being sorted as such;

```
public string PlainTextDescription
{
   get { 
       return this.Description.Replace(@"""","");
   }
}
```

and sorting like this;

```
FaqData = repo.FaqData.OrderBy(q => q.PlainTextDescription)
```

or by pre-populating the PlainTextDescription field using the logic, but only when the .Description value changes; this would be much more efficient because the String.Replace would only be called once each time the .Description changes - with the example above, the String.Replace code must be called every time the sorter needs to evaluate the PlainTextDescription field, which means we're doing the String.Replace many times instead of once.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick  FaqData = repo.FaqData.OrderBy(q => q.QuestionDescription.Replace(@"“", ""))

Comment: Maybe explain what you changed, and why it works now?

Comment: Answers with (unformatted) code are discouraged here, please explain what you did.

Comment: @DavidG - added explanation; although the use of @"""" would seem pretty obvious I would have thought.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you not only want to ignore quotes but anything that isn't A-Z.

All you need to do is include a function to `Where` that strips out anything you don't want.  To do that you can use a regular expression, like this:

```
var filtered = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^A-Za-z0-9]","")
```

Now to put it in a `Where` statement:

```
var tests = new[] { "Advance","Access","Binding","Broker",@"""Chain free"" deal","`Twas the night before Christams","#NotAllMen","Zenit","Quickly"};
var sorted = tests.OrderBy(s => Regex.Replace(s, @"[^A-Za-z0-9]",""));

foreach (var s in sorted)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Output:

```
Access
Advance
Binding
Broker
"Chain free" deal
#NotAllMen
Quickly
`Twas the night before Christams
Zenit
```

[Code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/58D0UF)